# XServer on Google Coral Dev Board

Tags: xorg, xserver, google-coral

Fairly simple question where the title says it all. I have trying for a few days and have been unsuccessful. Has anyone managed or know how to get XServer working on the Google Coral dev board?

I wish to use a desktop environment such as GNOME or KDE. These desktop environments use Xorg. However, whenever I start the Xserver it fails to create the resources.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As of now, Mendel only supports weston/wayland based display.

Comment: @Manoj GNOME and KDE both have support for Wayland protocols would it be feasible to do it using the Wayland service instead?